# Exception handler middleware not catching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm developping a web API with ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to implement a custom error handling middleware so I can throw standard exceptions that can be converted into a JSON response with the appropriate HTTP Status code.

For example if I do:

```
throw new NotFoundApiException("The object was not found");
```

I need it to be converted into:

```
StatusCode: 404
ContentType: application/json
ResponseBody: {"error": "The object was not found"}
```

Here is my **middleware**:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try {
            await next(context);
        } catch (ApiException ex) {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, ApiException exception)
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception.Message });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = exception.httpStatusCode;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

**Exceptions**

```
public class ApiException : System.Exception
{
    private int _httpStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    public ApiException() { }
    public ApiException(string message): base(message) { }

    public int httpStatusCode {
        get { return this._httpStatusCode; }
    }
}
public class NotFoundApiException : ApiException
{
    private int _httpStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    public NotFoundApiException() { }
    public NotFoundApiException(string message): base(message) { }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void Configure(/*...*/)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

**Controller action**

```
[HttpGet("object/{guid}")]
public WebMessage Get(Guid guid)
{
    throw new NotFoundApiException(string.Format("The object {0} was not found", guid));
//...
```

I can see the request entering my registered middleware but **the exception is not catched and simply thrown as usual**.

I'm suspecting a race condition or something similar, I don't know very much about them async functions actually.

Has someone got an idea why my exception is not catched ?

---

**edit** By continuing the execution with VisualStudio I can see the expected behavior: I'm finally getting my response.
Seems like the Exception is not really catched by the middleware but somehow processed afterwards.

Comment: Started running into this today also. Can't even catch `Exception` with identical middleware.

Comment: Well good luck and don't hesitate to tell if you find something :) I'll do the same

Answer (score 44, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to remove `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in `Startup.cs`

Comment: Yep that was the solution.

Comment: @Menahem using exception page is not very useful then returning error for an **API** call. If you want to respond with error page for some of your requests you can modify `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` to handle non API calls differently. Check the Invoke method and filter context.Request.Path for the right requests.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I found that `app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();` should be at the top of `Configure()` method.

Comment: Indeed, when the exception to be caught is thrown by another middleware, the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware should be configured before

Answer (score 5):

You can try also [Exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters).

*(of course, filters are not so flexible like as error handling middleware, which is better in general case, but - at least for me - filters are working fine without any issues)*

That's what I'm using:

```
public class ExceptionGlobalFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ExceptionGlobalFilter(ILoggerFactory lf)
    {
        logger = lf.CreateLogger("ExceptionGlobalFilter");
    }


    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var customObject = new CustomObject(context.Exception);

        //TODO: Add logs
        if (context.Exception is BadRequestException)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(customObject);
        }
        else if (context.Exception is NotFoundException)
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(customObject);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new OkObjectResult(customObject);
        }

        base.OnException(context);
    }


    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        await base.OnExceptionAsync(context);
        return;
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionGlobalFilter));
});
```

More info:

- [Introduction to Error Handling in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)
- [Exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters)
- [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters)
- [MVC Issue #5594](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5594)
- [ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs)

Comment: I tried it too, I got exactly the same behavior. But I just saw that by continuing the execution in VisualStudio, the response is what I expected. I'll update my question

Comment: There is few details: 1) It's depend on when (in what order) you register your middleware. 2) Be aware that once the headers for a response have been sent, you can't change the response's status code. The response must be completed or the connection aborted. 3) To handle an exception in ExceptionFilter, set the ExceptionContext.ExceptionHandled property to true or write a response. This stops propagation of the exception. 4) In ASP.NET 1.1, the response is not sent if you set ExceptionHandled to true and write a response. See the issue #5594 in the GitHub repository.

Comment: Especially verify if you are not affected by changes related to mentioned issue #5594: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5594. Short explanation of issue: In ASP.NET 1.1, the response is not sent if you set ExceptionHandled to true and write a response. In that scenario, ASP.NET Core 1.0 does send the response, and ASP.NET Core 1.1.2 will return to the 1.0 behavior.

Comment: Also, check the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs source code: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs - especially take a look on lines 50-54 `if (context.Response.HasStarted)` - perhaps it's your case?

Answer (score 1):

In my case `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` was written in the `Startup` after the exception handler middleware. The fix was simply by moving the exception handler middleware to be after it.

Answer (score -1):

@Pierre, I have met the same issue here when using Middleware as the global exception handler. The issue was caused by my mistake to wrote an "async void" method, I have throwed an exception in the method named "NewException":

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        NewException();
        return Ok("<h1>Hi, Welcome！</h1>");
    }

    private async void NewException()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("WTF");
    }
```

The exception [InvalidOperationException("WTF")] will not be catching by the Middleware, if I change the code snippet to :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        await NewException();
        return Ok("<h1>Hi, Welcome！</h1>");
    }

    private async Task NewException()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("WTF");
    }
```

The exception Middleware will catch it. Hope this help.